# BLACK SCREEN IN CINEMA 4D

Tags: cinema4d

I am having this ridiculous problem in Cinema 4D. Trying to render it gives me a black screen. I tried adding lights, infinite lights sky, turning off OpenGL rendering... but nothing happens!! I have searched everywhere for a solution but nobody seems to have a problem like this. It worked about a day ago. I updated my graphics driver too.. still nothing happens. Also, EVERYTHING is black, not just one object.[image]

Comment: It's possible that this could be a duplicate of this question: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17235/c4d-nothing-seems-to-fix-this-stupid-black-screen

Comment: Looks like a copy and paste. Unsure why. Closed as dupe.